# Python pymssql - Connecting to Named Instance

Tags: python, instance, pymssql, named

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server named instance from python 3.4 on a remote server, and get an error.

> File "C:\Scripts\Backups Integrity Report\Backup Integrity Reports.py", line 269, in 
>   conn = pymssql.connect(host=r'hwcvcs01\HDPS', user='My-office\romano', password='PASS', database='CommServ')
>   File "pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10178)
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n')

Other SQLs are connected without a problem. Also I manage to connect to the SQL using the Management Studio, from the same remote server.

Tried different ports, tried to connect to the host itself rather than the instance, and also tried pypyodbc.
What might be the problem?

Comment: Check if the "SQL Server Browser" service is running on the machine hosting the SQL Server instance to which you are trying to connect. Remote connections to a named instance often (always?) need to ask the Browser service which TCP port they should use.

Answer (score 4):

For a named instance that looks like this:

```
myhost\myinstance,1435
```

You can connect via pymssql with the following:

```
pymssql.connect(host='myhost', server='myinstance', port='1435', user='user', password='pw')
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the pymssql documentation on the pymssql Connection class, for a named instance containing database theDatabase, looking like this:
myhost\myinstance
You could connect as follows:
pymssql.connect(host=r'myhost\myinstance', database='theDatabase', user='user', password='pw')
The r-string is a so-called raw string that does not treat the '' as an escape.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Any ideas on if anything was changed in the newer versions?